# Greases pencils Line Art Modifier- Scratched line Error

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, freestyle, lineart

I use grease pencil line art. I want a neat outline. but I never want that to have scratched lines on its arms. How do I fix it?
[image]

[image]
If I turn off intersections, it is now a dashed line

[image]

Please don't forget to demonstrate pictures, gifs, or upload blends files. to make it easy to understand.

Comment: I am guessing there is a Z fight going on between duplicate arm meshes. Do the lines move around a lot when you orbit around the arm?

Comment: Thank you.  you have solved the problem.  I select a duplicate arm mesh to separate and then delete one mesh. now it has all gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments: There is a Z fight going on between duplicate arm meshes. Do the lines move around a lot when you orbit around the arm? If so, find the duplicate mesh (either in the same object or separate), and delete it.